# Is there a way in Cloudformation to make IAM policies use conditional Resources

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a bunch of cloud formation templates that have conditional resources in them for alerting. Only the prod stacks get these resources created. I need my IAM policy I am creating in the stack to reflect those conditional resources. So far I am not finding a way to do this. I have tried using Condition: in a separate policy document and it seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd check out the `Fn::If` intrinsic function. It's really useful for stuff like this. For example, if I have an `ShouldGenerateBucket` condition, and two buckets, `constant-bucket` that will always be created and `conditional-bucket` that might be, I can use that in my policy like:

```
Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
Properties: 
  PolicyName: "RoleAccess"
  PolicyDocument: 
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement: 
      -
        Effect: "Allow"
        Action: "s3:*""
        Resource:
          - arn:aws:s3:::constant-bucket
          - !If
            - ShouldGenerateBucket
            - arn:aws:s3:::conditional-bucket
            - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

This will add the additional resource resource if `ShouldGenerateBucket` is `true`, but ignore it otherwise.

Comment: Ok thanks, i am about to test this out. I trying to test this out be CF seems to be giving me issued upload my template. I think they are having an issue.

Comment: Oh, yeah, if you're in `us-east-1` it seems to be having an [increased error rate at the moment](http://status.aws.amazon.com/), and it's a fairly big dependency for CloudFormation